# Can we avoid asking sim reading user permission in Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there anyway to avoid asking user permissions in Android? I am trying to read sim card information, and I do not want to ask for call/phone info reading pemission!

Comment: Simple...you want to read then you need the permission to

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Requesting user permission on Android is a tool to avoid unwanted use of private data and personal information for untrustful applications.

Also, any collected data from users phone must be acknowledged by them.